# JQuery Enabling and Disabling based on Select Change or Input Entry

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I already have one JQ that requires a selection from the first drop down in order to click Save. If you look at the example, you'll see that I have an optional Add Task.

I can't have someone select a task type then forget the due date or type in a due date and forget the task type. A php-side validation won't work for various other reasons, so I'm wondering if there is an easy JQuery to disable Save if only one of the two has content.

(P.S. - let me know if you get the character references) :)

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/internetjason/z18rrax1/)**

HTML:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="POST">

    <h4>Create New Note</h4>

    <div>
    <select class="form-control" id="fdispositionid" name="fdispositionid">
        <option value="0"></option>
        <option value="4">Set Appointment</option>
        <option value="8">Sent Email</option>
        <option value="7">Left Voicemail</option>
    </select>
    </div>

    <div>
    <textarea class="form-control" name="fnotes" id="fnotes" rows="5"></textarea>
    </div>

    <h4>Create New Task <small>(optional)</small></h4>

    <div>
    <select class="form-control" name="fassignedto" id="fassignedto">
        <option value=0></option>
        <option value=1 selected>Shawn Spencer</option>
        <option value=2>Burton Guster</option>
    </select>
    </div>

    <div>
    <select class="form-control" name="ftasktypeid" id="ftasktypeid">
        <option value=0></option>
        <option value="6">Appointment</option>
        <option value="1">Call Back</option>
        <option value="5">Campaign</option>
    </select>
    </div>

    <div>
    <input type="text" name="fduedate2" id="fduedate2" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Date" />
    </div>

    <div>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" id="notesave" name="notesave" onclick="return fnsavenote();" disabled> Save Note</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

JS:

```
$('#fdispositionid').change(function(){
    var selected = $(this).val();
    if(selected == '0'){
      $('#notesave').attr("disabled", "disabled");
    }
    else{
      $('#notesave').removeAttr("disabled");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can check if duedate has any value inside your ifcase like this

```
$('#fdispositionid,#fduedate2').on('change keyup',function(){
    var selected = $('#fdispositionid').val();
    var date=$('#fduedate2').val();
    if(selected == '0' || date==""){
      $('#notesave').prop("disabled", true);
    }
    else{
      $('#notesave').prop("disabled",false);
    }
});
```

**Note:** Use `.prop()` for property values

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Alfie/z18rrax1/1/)

Comment: The problem is that this is not required unless someone selects the Task Type right above it. Since adding a task is optional, I don't want to disable Save unless the user begins to create a task and just hasn't finished. I'm not sure if that makes sense.

Comment: @internetjason I think i understand, updated fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/Alfie/z18rrax1/2/

Comment: That's still not quite it. I wonder if this is more complicated than it needs to be. 

Save enables once I select a Disposition - that works. But once that has been selected, I want Save to disable again if Task Type or Date is entered but the other one isn't. So I select Disposition, Save is enabled. I select a Task Type and Save then should be Disabled until I enter a date, then it is Enabled again.